# how to use cmd commands for two different accounts

Tags: windows, git, github, environment-variables, virtual-machine

I have an account on github and also an account on bitbucket. When I use git commands, like `commit`, `push`, the data gets stored on my bitbucket account.

What can I do to be able to use github account as well?

Would creating another `Windows` user account help? Would installing a virtual machine help? I'm looking at the easiest and most fool-proof ways, because I'm wary of accindentally commiting personal stuff to bitbucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to change your information depending on where you want to commit and push.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

So if you want to use your github account you change your config to that account, if you want to commit to bitbucket you change your config to that account.